# Is there a way of changing air refractivity?

Tags: optics, refraction, air, hologram

Is there any kind of way/equipment that can change the air refractive index? For example, a mirage is hot air refracting light in a certain way, making it look like water.

The best I could think of were using a heat gun (basically a hair dryer), a water humidifier or an infrared laser. Aside from the water humidifier, the two options sound too dangerous with a doubtful effectiveness.

I'm asking this because I'm interested on volumetric displays (also known as "Holograms"), by increasing the refractivity of air, one could make these holograms quite easily. The smoke they use [is the easiest way of making this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCnEPlqIv1o), but it has a limit on where it can be used.

Comment: Are you trying to increase or decrease the refractive index? Heating air (at constant pressure) would decrease its refractive index.

Comment: @Puk I didn't know that in order to make a mirage you would need to decrease the refractive index, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refractive index of air depends mostly on temperature and pressure, but also on relative humidity and CO2 content.
See [here](https://emtoolbox.nist.gov/Wavelength/Documentation.asp#EdlenorCiddor) and [here](https://emtoolbox.nist.gov/Wavelength/Documentation.asp#AppendixA) for a full discussion of the ways to calculate the index of refraction of air.

A simplified version:

n = 1 + 7.84E-4 * P/(273+T) - 1.5E-11*RH*(T^2 + 160)

where n is the index of refraction of air, P is the pressure in kPa, T is the temperature in Celcius, and RH is the relative humidity in percent (0..100). The influence of CO2 is small. Typically encountered have an effect of about 1/10^8 on the index of refraction.

Considerations for a display:
CO2 has too small an influence and is toxic in significant amounts. P is probably uncontrollable without producing unacceptable loud noise. T is possible to control using grids of lasers tuned to some wavelength that air absorbs, but you'll have control issues from the temperature in the previous frame and pixel, as well as the neighboring pixel. That will also draw a lot of power. Humidity isn't large either unless you have droplet formation. So basically, you want a display based on mid-air water droplets. Two approaches there: either have computer controlled droplet emitters, and the droplets rain down. This has been donw. You can either [accept watching the image fall](https://www.water-display.com/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3MWlzvTXgwMVg1CRBR0m2w6EEAEYASAAEgLCHPD_BwE) or [put a strobe light on it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_z7lAxEMF74).
Or you can induce momentary cloud formation in supersaturated air -- maybe supersaturated with something other than water. This is how cloud chambers work. I'd pursue that. Cloud formation would have the advantage of looking white rather than a wiggly transparent view of whatever is behind the display.
To induce cloud formation, you need to have both dissolved fluid above the saturation point in the presence of nucleation centers. So you could approach this by either

A) inducing fluid to rise above saturation (100% relative humidity), in the presence of a some dusty nucleation centers. Or

B) you can have supersaturated fluid in the presence of some sort of smart particles that can be toggled between being nucleation centers and not.

Route A seems like it'll involve violently wiggling the air pressure, making a terrible noise in the process. Route B sounds like plausible nanotechnology. Let me sketch an idea for that: You have a frame around 4 of the 6 sides of a volumetric display viewed through the open sides in the Z direction. On one (X-Z plane) side is a grid of lasers of wavelength L1, and on other side (Y-Z plane) is another grid of lasers of wavelength L2, such that in the volume of the display lasers of both wavelengths can intersect. Then in the middle of the display is a supersaturated solution of some fluid, and a suspension of nanoparticles. The nanoparticles are covered in something--maybe a designer protein--that converts from hydrophobic to hydrophilic when hit in quick succession by photons of wavelength L1 and L2, going from non-nucleating centers to nucleating centers. Then they go back after a few milliseconds. So, at the intersection of the two lasers a cloud forms. Maybe the lasers can be out of the visible spectrum. Figuring that out in detail is a job for a chemist, and I'm not a chemist.

If the resulting clouds are dense, a significant difficulty may be formed clouds blocking the lasers. But then you could have laser arrays on all sides, so that a 3D shape can be hit from the top and bottom, left and right, and make a 3D shell.

Answer (score 1):

Add CO$_2$. That is denser and increases the index of refraction.

Answer (score 1):

The refraction of light by air is dependent on the molecular polarization
of the (mainly nitrogen) air molecules.   There is no good way to
increase the molecular polarization properties, but one can
change the air density, with sound waves.

Alas, for visible light holography, the high resolution required
will require very high sonic frequencies, and those are strongly
attenuated in air.   Prospects for holography seem... dim.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to locally increase the refractivity of air is to set off a powerful explosion nearby. The resulting shock wave is discontinuous in pressure and density and, if a smoke tracer is present, the shock wave becomes easily visible as a kink in the smoke trail. This method was used to study the atmospheric dynamics of atomic bomb blasts and it really works!

You might have some issues with adapting it to your specific application though.

Answer (score 0):

Either heat the air or just change its composition. You've already noted the first by your example of a mirage.